# Button Value outside of the Form is not being posted

Tags: jquery, forms, .post

I have this form. The submit button is outside of the form.

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="John Smith">
</form> 
<button type="submit" name="submit_save" for="myform" value="s">Save</button>
```

JS detects my Clicking on the button and then I use jQuerty $.post/Ajax to post. (with serialize())
All is almost fine I can see my input value posted, BUT not the value for the submit button itself.

Now if I place the button inside the form, on submit i will have both value posted.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the problem if you place the button inside the form if you want its value to be posted?

Comment: *How* are you calling `serialize()`? If it's `$("#myform").serialize()` then why would expect it to include anything that's not in myform.  If you're generating the POST yourself, then just include the submit button's value in the `data:`.   If you include that code, we could probably advise.